# Creating geoprocessing package (*.gpk) that contains more than one model?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, wpf, arcgis-runtime, geoprocessing-package

I'm making gpk (= geoprocessing package) packages for ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.2.

I'm making several models, and wanted to know if there is a way for including several models in one gpk file or do i need to make several gpks and move between them with code?

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple models to a geoprocessing package by running them and having their results preserved within the Results window.

Esri Help page: [Adding a result to a geoprocessing package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00570000007m000000)

When you will click Add Result, all the results of the models' runs will be listed and you can choose the one you need.

[image]